# How would you combine DC power, bi-directional serial data, and an RF signal on a single 50-Ohm coax feedline?

Tags: rf, dc, serial, serial-bus, ham-radio

I would like to power a remote device and communicate with it over some serial protocol on the far-end of a 50-Ohm coax feedline (RS232, i2c, SPI, etc), while at the same time sending/receiving an RF signal (144-148MHz ham band).

A bias tee is simple enough to get power down the line, but how could I add serial communications?

- Are there existing components or ICs to facilitate such a data encapsulation?
- What bitrate can you achieve?

Comment: _"RS232, i2c, SPI, etc"_ - so any _one_ of these would be suitable? What bit rate do you _need_, and why do you need this communication channel?

Comment: You might be interested in this [opamp-based circulator](http://www.wenzel.com/wp-content/uploads/RFDesign31.pdf). with a set at both ends behind suitable filters you could send bi-directional comms data without having to do any modulation or mixing. You might have to have a think about tweaking the voltage offsets though so you superimpose the signal on to of DC power and add a bias-tee to separate it all from the RF.

Comment: I2C and SPI both require more than one wire (plus ground), so how do you plan to send them over a single coaxial cable?

Comment: Use some type of low power RF 900 MHz telemetry scheme for the serial data. DC is easy. There are DC injectors for RF already. The 900 MHz telemetry will not interfere with your 144 MHz TX/RX. You will want to use an attenuator for your 900 MHz stuff since you have a direct cable connection rather than over-the-air.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They weren't originally designed for it, but I have seen applications that use bidirectional radio chips such as the TI [CC1101](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc1101.pdf) to pass control/status data in both directions through a coax alongside DC power and another RF signal.

The chip handles a lot of the details and is relatively easy to set up with a microcontroller. In fact, in one design, a very simple "soft core" microcontroller embedded in an FPGA takes care of it. The data rate can be set anywhere from 0.6 to 600 kbps.

Comment: Something like this seems like the best solution. If the OP is going to transmit on 2m, then it might be necessary to put good high-pass filters in front of the radio chips to make sure there is adequate attenution of the 2m TX.

Comment: I really like this! Nice catch and +1!

Comment: The TI looks like a good option, I'm also looking at the Si4455 (https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/368/Si4455-1397974.pdf).  They look similar, but do you see a notable difference?

Comment: I agree -- on paper, they appear to be functionally very similar. I have no direct experience with the Si4455, however.

Comment: Just to throw in another option - Semtech SX1232. I have found Semtech's software stack somewhat easier to work with than CC110x. The downside here is lower baudrate - they max out at 300 kbps.

Comment: A slightly better solution would use an integrated RF + MCU part. Espressif, TI, SiLabs and others have such parts.

Answer (score 1):

> *How would you combine*
>
> - *DC power,*
> - *bi-directional serial data, and*
> - *an RF signal on*
> - *a \$\color{red}{\text{single}}\$ 50-Ohm coax feed-line?*

Let's not forget what the question says regards cables: -

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{the single coax feed-line}}}$$

Regular UART level serial data comms would interfere with RF reception but you could certainly modulate the data so that its spectrum is beyond the bandwidth of the RF signal and you would easily achieve tens of megabits per second and not cause the RF transmission a problem. Easy enough to do with a Colpitts oscillator and a varactor diode. If you need more sophistication wrap the oscillator around a PLL such as the [ADF4110](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4110_4111_4112_4113.pdf).

You can modulate up and down data on two different carriers so that full duplex can be achieved. You can easily achieve tens of Mbps in both directions. Operate the up-link at circa 350 MHz and the down-link at circa 450 MHz.

Forget about raw SPI or I2C or RS232 and think about UART data that is scrambled and modulated onto a carrier (basic example of scrambling): -

[image]

Here's another example of scrambling and descrambling: -

[image]

This will keep bandwidth under control and away from the RF and the down-stream data (also using scrambled data but a different carrier frequency). Data is unscrambled using basically the same circuit but you do need a receive data clock recovery circuit at each end to successfully restore data into its unscrambled format. Or you could use Manchester encoding but this eats into the bandwidth and will eventually restrict high-speed data rates compared to scrambling the data.

But the devil is in the detail and if your RF signal is really low energy (i.e. a direct antenna signal), then you have to take care so that data energy (albeit modulated) does not splash across the RF data spectrum. That's why it's important for the data to use: -

$$\color{purple}{\boxed{\text{the bandwidth above the RF link spectrum}}}$$

However, if the bandwidth requirements for the up and down-streams are not that great (i.e. kilo bits per second) then it can be easily done below the RF part of the spectrum (144 MHz to 148 MHz). Full duplex may not be required and this also simplifies things.

You could fit multiple low-speed data carriers between DC and RF but, the question asked this: -

$$\color{green}{\boxed{\text{what bit-rate could be achieved}}}$$

And, in the absence of any other information, there is superior bandwidth available above the 148 MHz area and, it can be used without any exotic type of modulation. I'm thinking of plain ordinary FSK for the data links. Been there etc..

Providing DC power is trivial in comparison because its bandwidth (i.e. the current fluctuations demanded by the load) can be limited fairly well with decent filters.

This type of design is really down to how good you can design filters.

Comment: how would the UART data be mixed into the carrier, what do you mean by "scrambled"?  Can you come up with a simple circuit?  What encoding would you use?

Comment: The block diagram in my answer gives a clue - X1 to X7 are d type flip flops. The round symbols with a plus sign are exclusive or gates. Virtually the same circuit de-scrambles the scrambled data back to normal data. The trick is recovering the clock signal from the scrambled signal so that it can be properly clocked through the d types and exclusive or gates.

Answer (score 1):

frequency devision multiplexing:

With consumer satellite hardware signalling is done using voltage modulation and 22 kHz tone bursts

if the data rate is low I'd send the signal up the line by modulating the supply voltage (eg switching between 13V and 15V )
and signal back down using 22kHz bursts.

> Are there existing components or ICs to facilitate such a data encapsulation?

you'd probably need to build your own drivers. to interface between the UARTS and the cable

> What bitrate can you achieve?

How good can you build VLF filters?

Another option might be to use POTS modem type signals. Chips exist for that, but again you need to separate the VLF data signals from the VHF radio signals and probably need to design your own line drivers. 9600 bits per seconds is probably possible this way without too much effort. 300 bits per second with considerably less effort.